# function that reverses digits, takes into consideration the sign

Tags: python

I've looked on the site to try and figure out how to do this but I'm still stuck.

My function is supposed to reverse digits, so reverse_digits(8765) returns 5678. This is easily done by :

```
def reverse_digits(num):
    return int(str(num)[::-1])
```

However, my code needs to 1) test if it is a negative and keep it negative (so -8765 returns -5678) and 2) I think I should test to see if num is actually an int.

So far I have

```
def reverse_digits(num):
   num = str(num)[::-1]
   if num == '-':
       minus = 1
       num = num[:-1]
   else: 
       minus = 0    
   int(num)  
   if minus == 1:
       num = num*-1
   else:
       num = num   
   return num
```

It works for digits without a '-', but returns '' when it has a '-'.

I was originally trying to put the test to see if it is an int at the beginning od the loop like

```
if (num != int):
    print("wrong type") 
    sys.exit()
else:
   (the rest of my above code)
```

but that wouldn't work for me. Should I put all the code in a while loop so I can use continue/break? 
Thanks!

Comment: would say, it raises a `ValueError` for negative numbers.

Comment: You can do `if num < 0: sign = -1 else sign = 1` before you convert to string `str(num)`. layter you can do one line `num = int(num)* sign`. Line `int(num)` does nothing - it have to be `num = int(num)`. To test variable type use `isinstance(num, int)`

Answer (score 4):

Just don't put the `-` into the reversed string:

```
def reverse_digits(num):
    return (-1 if num<0 else 1) * int(str(abs(num))[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the isdigit() string method.

```
def reverse_digit(num):
      num_str = str(num)[::-1].strip('-')
      if not num_str.isdigit():
           <do what u want>
      if num < 0:
         return -int(num_str)
      else:
         return int(num_str)
```